# Managing subsites through a CMS

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system

I’m working on a project (one I’ve inherited) with one main website for the purposes of gathering contact information from potential customers and a collection of sub sites which serve the same purpose.  Each of these sites has a different design and each one is served from a separate directory under the document root directory.  Each of these sub sites is also served from the same URL as the main site with a different directory specified in the URL for each one of these subsites, e.g. “http://www.example.com/subsite/”.

The problem as it is now is that our web designers have to make manual changes to the HTML in each of the files for these sub sites whenever a change is needed.  Ideally, they would like to be able to manage these sites and make changes to them in a more rapid way and without having to make manual changes to something like 60+ sites each containing potentially 10-15 pages of HTML.

I’ve been doing research into various solutions and I’m not sure which would be the best to manage something like this.  These sites are all built in PHP and I’ve been looking into CMS solutions such as Drupal, SilverStripe, and MODX but I’m not certain if they would meet our needs.  I don’t have a lot of experience working with a CMS so I’m hoping someone with more experience can provide some insight.  Any suggestions anyone can make regarding how best to handle something like this are greatly appreciated.

If I’ve left out any information that might be helpful/necessary in someone providing advice just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any CMS will do what you need.

If I've understood well every subsite share the same domain, but only resides in a subdirectory.

For example with **MODX** you could define different templates with specific design for every subsite.
All subsites however could share some chunks (html code) or snippets (php code), so that a change in shared things applies to all subsites.

You can easily migrate the exisiting design to MODX:

http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2009/03/28/building-a-website-with-modx-for-newbies-part-1-introduction/

and find the additional pieces you need:

http://modx.com/extras/

Comment: I figured that MODX would do pretty much what was needed, but I wanted to make sure that this was the case since I've never worked with it.